# Prevent chrome from filling select field on history backward/forward

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a form with custom `onsubmit` handler which reads the value selected in a `<select>` input.

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit()">
  <select id="selector" name="selector">
    <option selected hidden disabled value>Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When I open this page in Chrome, select a value from the dropdown and go one page back in my history, then one page forth to land on the page with the form again, that option is already selected while accessing the field via JS with `$('#selector').val()` returns me an empty value.

I already tried specifying `autocomplete="off"` on the `<select>` tag without success. Also disabling cache for that page didn't help.

Any suggestions on how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to strong history-form-caching of chrome.

I didn't find a CSS or HTML solution for this too. So I did it with JS.
Everytime a page is shown - no matter if the page is loaded from history cache or is just reloaded - the browser triggers the "pageshow"-event.

With jQuery:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    $('#your_form_id')[0].reset();
});
```

With plain JS:

```
var oForm2Reset = document.getElementById('your_form_id');
if( oForm2Reset ) {
    window.onpageshow = function() {
        oForm2Reset.reset();
    };
}
```